# Finding a path from any given node to another node

Tags: php, search

I'm stuck on a problem I can't seem to solve. 
this is the problem:

I've got a database that contains a table with connections.
example:
**node1** || **node 2**
a     || b 
a     || c 
b || d 
b || e 
e || h 
h|| e 
e|| b 
b || a

I would like to know the shortest path from any given node to any other node. I want to save all the nodes that are in the path from lets say: h to a or a to h or b to a etc.

This should be done using, sql( to get the info out of the database) and php (to decide what is the shortest path and return the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using djkstra method. It Is possibile to find with Dijkstra the shortest path from any given node to any other node and from a node to another